# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when converting UTF-32 (HEX) to string

Tags: c#, hex, utf-32

I'm having trouble converting some of the UTF-32 HEX to string. I'm getting this error message

> "A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and
>   should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff).
>   Parameter name: utf32"

when using this code

```
int decodedInt = Convert.ToInt32("D8F5", 16);
string decodedStr = char.ConvertFromUtf32(decodedInt);
```

when I use this HEX "9FDB", it works without any issues. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a surrogate and not valid on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codepoints in the range 0xD800..0xDFFF are used by UTF-16 to encode codepoints outside the basic multilingual plane via a surrogate pair. They never occur in UTF-32 encoded text.

That's why the error said

> should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff)

Comment: how can i convert these type of hex